# Combining countRows with a having clause in esqueleto

Tags: haskell, esqueleto

I'm working on a very simple toy API to improve my Haskell skills.
The relevant database table is called `ingredients` and has some fields `(id, name, category)`.

I'm now trying to get a selection query working that shows possible duplicates. It does this in a naive way. If two ingredients have the same name, it might be a duplicate. It is however allowed to have ingredients with the same name, it's just that they might be duplicates.
It doesn't really matter if this restraint doesn't make sense since it's just a toy project.

Basically I would like to get the following query in esqueleto:

```
SELECT name FROM ingredients
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

I succeeded in creating the following esqueleto code

```
getDuplicateIngredientsStmt :: SqlPersistT (LoggingT IO) [E.Value Text]
getDuplicateIngredientsStmt = E.select
  $ E.from
  $ \ingredients -> do
    E.groupBy $ ingredients E.^. IngredientName
    E.having $ (E.countRows :: SqlExpr (E.Value Int)) E.>. E.val 1
    return $ ingredients E.^. IngredientName
```

This all works and compiles, great. But is this really as simple as it gets?
I'm mainly frustrated with me having to cast the `countRows` to  an `SqlExpr` is this really necessary?

If I leave out the cast I get the following error (telling me I need the cast)

```
Ambiguous type variable ‘typ0’ arising from a use of ‘countRows’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Num typ0)’ from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘typ0’ should be.
```

Comment: You can put the annotation on the `1` at the end of the line, `... E.val (1 :: Int)`, as the numeric type is the only part that can't be inferred. Though I am a bit confused why it's not just defaulting to `Integer` - do you have a line like `default ()` in the file somewhere?

Comment: I have rewritten the code a bit to the experimental syntax of esqueleto but that also still needs the type hint. [Here is a gist of the entire file](https://gist.github.com/arnegoeteyn/f979d1e8dccfe917202a638b5fc0e36e)

No `default ()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you're already using the `TypeApplications` extension. That provides an even easier approach.

```
E.having $ E.countRows E.>. E.val @Int 1
```

That sets the only free type variable in the type of `E.val` to `Int`, which does everything you need.

As for why it's necessary, it's because the types of `E.val` and `E.>.` introduce a `PersistField` constraint, so `1` ends up being inferred to have the type `(PersistField t, Num t) => t`. This prevents defaulting because the regular defaulting rules apply only when the constraints are in a minimal set that the compiler knows about. (The [`ExtendedDefaultRules` extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/ghci.html#extension-ExtendedDefaultRules) would cause it to default to `Integer` because it knows what to do with the `Num` portion of the constraint, but I don't think that's really what you're after.)

I'm just baffled that the error message you quoted doesn't mention *both* constraints. That would have made the lack of defaulting much more immediately obvious.

Comment: Would there be a downside to using the ExtendedDefaultRules extension?

Comment: @ArneGoeteyn The only potential downsides I can see is that the default Integral type is `Integer` rather than `Int` and if you have warnings on you'll get a defaulting warning. If you don't mind those, feel free to turn it on.